# Does a fieldset's form attribute apply to its child controls?

Tags: html, forms

From my initial testing, it appears that a fieldset's "form" attribute does not get passed to child controls.

I can't tell if I've got a different issue, or if that's the way fieldset is supposed to work.  Seems like a fairly useless attribute on fieldset if so...

```
<body>

  <section>
    <form id="separate-form"></form>
  </section>

  <fieldset form="separate-form">
    <input type="text" value="this doesn't get submitted to #separate-form ?">
    <button>submit</button>
  </fieldset>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of April 2018, and testing on Chrome/Firefox, it seems as the though the answer is "No". A fieldset's `form` attribute does NOT apply to its child controls.

I had to iterate through all form elements setting the attribute for each.